# how to use pthread for not just void functions with void argument in C/C++？

Tags: c, types, casting, pthreads

I wanna call multiple functions and deal with their return values (using `pthread_join`) in `main()`, but they are all **int** functions with **multiple non-void** arguments, and the definition of `pthread_create` is:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t * thread, 
               const pthread_attr_t * attr,
               void * (*start_routine)(void *), 
               void *arg);
```

all examples of the `start_routine` I found in the internet are type of `void *` with type of single `void *` argument, is it possible to call int functions with multiple non-void type arguments in `pthread_create`?

Comment: Did you try something that did not work?

Comment: If I'm using int funtion, it will be compiled with errors

Comment: Show the function decl, and show the *exact* error. In short, show whatever you've tried that is *not* working, and please, *please* put it in your *question*, not here in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You want to wrap the `int` function into a function of the required type.

So assuming you want to return an `int` you might do it like this:

<sup>(The example assume C99 and leaves out relevant error checking for the sake of readebility.)</sup>

```
#include <inttypes.h> /* for intptr_t */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct S
{
  int x;
  int y;
};

int sum(int x, int y)
{
  return x + y;
}

void * thread_function(void * pv)
{
  struct S * ps = pv;
  pthread_exit((void *) (intptr_t) sum(ps->x, ps->y));
}


int main(void)
{
  struct S s = {41, 1};
  pthread_t pt;
  pthread_create(&pt, NULL, thread_function, &s);

  void * pv;
  pthread_join(pt, &pv);

  int z = (intptr_t) pv;
  printf("%d + %d = %d\n", s.x, s.y, z);
 }
```

This prints:

```
41 + 1 = 42
```

The casting to and from `intptr_t` is necessary to assure the misuse of a pointer value as an integer does not violate the C-Standard.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) you will see that the function argument is

```
void *(*start_routine) (void *).
```

You cannot pass a different type of function to start routine.

You can use (void *) to pass an argument to start_routine.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the pThread pointer to some type compatible with integer. Better solution is to put the entire functionality in a wrapper function. Please refer to the below link:

[C++, create a pthread for a function with a return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025664/c-create-a-pthread-for-a-function-with-a-return-type)

Comment: Casting the function is a bad idea. Doing so would provoke undefiend behaviour.

Comment: @alk : I agree casting is always a bad idea. That why i suggested the better solution would be to wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understood the question.
You want to call a function with a signature like

```
int myfunct(int a, int b, int c)
```

then define a struct like this

```
struct my_funct_param_t
{
    int a ;
    int b ;
    int c ; 
} ;
```

and a wrapper to use as start routine

```
void *myfunct1(void *arg)
{
    my_funct_param_t *arg1 = (my_funct_param_t *)arg ;
    myfunct(arg1->a, arg1->b, arg1->c) ;
 ....
}
```

The code that starts the thread must create the my_funct_patam_t object and fill in accordingly. Beware of this object lifetime....